# C# Updating Form1 when closing Form2

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, treeview

I have a situation where a user clicks a button on Form1 to open Form2. Form1's load event populates a treeview based on data returned from the database. When they input data into Form2, the database updates, but the treeview does not. If I close and reopen the winform, then it pulls in the new data.

I have been digging for a few hours now, and I found out how to call the getdata method in Form1 from Form2, but it doesn't work. I can trace it in debug mode, and verified my dataReader contains the new value, but the treeview does not update. I did it like this.

```
//In form 2
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.getData();
```

Nothing happens. If I say frm.Show() then it opens a new Form1 window with the updated data, but I want the treeview to update in the already opened Form1 window.

I believe this is the root of the problem. Any call I make to frm happens in a new window. How do I access the existing Form1 window's getData() method from Form2?

Comment: How are you creating and showing Form2 in Form1?

Comment: While opening Form2 try pass reference of treeview by `ref` keyword in contructor of Form2 like ` public Form2(ref TreeView tv) `, after evry operation on Form2 update treeView also and refresh Form1() on Form2() closing, Hope u understand.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you are creating Form2 and showing it in Form1, i.e. are you using `.Show` or `.ShowDialog` if it is the later all you have to do is use the `DialogResult` to determine whether or not to call your `getData`method.

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
if (frm2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    getData();
}
```

If you are using the `Show` Method you can listen for Form2's `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event and respond to that in your Form1. Like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.FormClosed += frm2_FormClosed;
    frm2.Show();
}

void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    getData(); 
}

private void getData()  //Surrogate for your getData method
{
    MessageBox.Show("Getting Data");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the thing I understand is that you want to have a reference to the form1 that already exists. you might use `Application` to have any access to the forms.

like this code:

```
 private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 myfrm =Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
            myfrm.GetData();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to complete this task is to have a method on form1 that is called after the form2 modal is closed.

**Form1**

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an instance of form 2
    Form2 secondForm = new Form2();

    // Display form 2
    secondForm.ShowDialog();

    // Call a method on form1 to update information on form 1. Any code listed after 
    // the show dialog call will process after Form2 is closed.
    UpdateForm1();
}

private void UpdateForm1()
{
    // Code your updates to form1 here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are creating a new instance of Form1 instead of passing in a reference to the original Form1.  If you pass in a reference to the original Form1; you will be updating that instances.  Not a new one.

See this post for similar problem to what I think your experiencing.

[refreshing treeview component from other form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618383/refreshing-treeview-component-from-other-form)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

```
//In Form1 opening Form2
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Owner = this;
frm.Show();

//Exemple to call functions to FORM1 from FORM2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frmParent = (Form1)this.Owner;
    frmParent.testeFunction();
    frmParent.InsertInGrid(textBox1.Text);
}
```

So, basically you need to create one function in Form1 to call from Form2 (passing Parameters).
I hope this help